# Formal way of some sentences

Tags: expressions

What is the formal way of following sentences? I see them too much in memes and informal speaking, I know the meaning, but do not the formal way.
"You don't say?"
"Challenge Accepted"
"Bitch Please"
"RIP [something]"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest asking for separate questions as there are likely some different interpretations of each of those phrases.

Comment: +1 At times, I agree to ask multiple questions in one question if they all are related and have short answers.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this question could go either way. On one hand, the phrases are somewhat related (at least the first three seem to be, in that they can all be used in conjunction with some level of incredulity). On the other hand, one could write a whole essay on a phrase like _Bitch, please_ (or at least on the word [_bitch_](http://reallifebh.com/btch-please-how-to-use-the-word-bitch-correctly)). I'm inclined to let this stand as-is for now – but not because @Todd is wrong. Also, the O.P. might want to consider asking more than one question  next time a similar situation rolls around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here is how you can tell those sentences in a formal way. Note that there could be many ways but I'm writing what I find closest.

**You don't say** - used when you agree with someone, or surprised, or utter this in sarcastic way.

> *"His behavior is very strange."* - *Yeah! **I agree*** (agreeing). 
>   *"Jack won the championship."* - *Ah, **did he**? Don't tell me* (surprising). 
>   *"You know, there's no sun in the night."* - *Wow, **I never knew that**!* (sarcastic).

**Challenge accepted** - the speaker is ready to accept the tough task that you think is not possible.

> *"It's impossible to finish this task by 1800 hr."* - *Do you think so? Well, **I'll do [finish] it**.*

**Bitch Please** - A response used when someone says something stupid or when somebody tries stupid on you

> *"...so you understand the scheme? If you give me 100 bucks, I'll make it double in a week."* - *Ah, **come on! Stop this**.*

**RIP [somebody]** - Rest In Peace. This is said when a person has died and you pray that their soul rest in peace - This is abbreviation rather than informal way of expressing grief. You may use the whole phrase and it's okay.

**However**...

**RIP [something]** - a tongue in cheek comment when some**thing** is no more in the market, internet or the like - Here, you don't need to be formal.

Check this -

### [image]

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that, at least in the U.S., "You don't say!" is considered rather old-fashioned, while "Challenge accepted!" is more newfangled. I have an easy time imagining my grandfather saying, "You don't say!", and my daughter saying, "Challenge accepted!", but it's hard to imagine it the other way around.

Comment: @J.R. "You don't say" is mostly used sarcastically (especially in the context of memes)